# How to await on async function and collect the response

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise

Until now, I thought `await` makes my program synchronous. However, I see that `await` only waits for `async` function to be resolved with a promise then the whole programs continues to run. So, what is the right way to wait & collect the response from async function?

Original code:

```js
let result={
  name:'',
  country:''
};
const data = await query.getCachedData(did); 
result.name = data.name; // undefined
result.country = data.country;//undefined
console.log(result);
```

I don't know why but awaiting on the async function result works:

```js
let result={
  name:'',
  country:''
};
const data = await query.getCachedData(did); 
result.name = await data.name; //'Jon'
result.country = await data.country;// 'US'
console.log(result);
```

But I am not sure if this is the solution.

Since `getCachedData` returns the promise, I thought this may be the right way but the `then()`/`catch()` didn't execute.

```js
query.getCachedData(did).then((tfnData) => {
  result.name = data.name; 
  result.country = data.country;
  console.log(result);
}).catch((dbError) => {
  console.log(dbError);
});
```

Can anyone correct me to get the `result` the right way?

Comment: I'm going to reiterate Robert's comment since I don't think he has enough rep to leave an actual comment.  Please provide the source of `getCachedData` or provide enough information to reproduce this issue.  What DB library are you using?  How can we cause this to happen on our end?  Please read [mre].

Comment: is query.getCachedData an async method? can you also show us what this method look like? I doubt this is an async method or it return a promise since you cannot await it and you cannot execute then/catch on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Promise is the return from a async function. The result is maybe not finish yet. 
That is why you can await a method (like you did it). This will set the return from the function when the calculation is complied.

Or you can make use of 'then':

```
const data1 = await query.getCachedData(did);
//data1 has a value at this point of code

const data2;
query.getChachedData(did).then((result)=>{data2 = result});
//data2 can have a value or will get one later (this is async) at this point of code
```

With Promise all you can let multiple methods run asynchronous and wait for all at once.
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```
const callStack = [];

const data1;
const data2;
callStack.push(query.getChachedData(did).then((result)=>{data1 = result}));
callStack.push(query.getChachedData(did).then((result)=>{data2 = result}));
//run both query Methods at asynchronous 
await Promise.all(callStack);
//data1 and data2 hava a value at this point of code
```

Answer (score 1):

> Until now, I thought await makes my program synchronous

`Async/await` makes the code to looks like synchronous, but behind is just **syntactic sugar** for promises in Javascript. **Really?** [Yes](https://git.io/fjrvf)

Is just `return thePromise().then(result => result)`

> I see that await only waits for async function to be resolved with a promise then the whole programs continues to run

When you work with promises, they not make Node.js code run synchronous, in the other hand, promises allow you to write flows that appear synchronous.

> So, what is the right way to wait & collect the response from async function?

According to your example, the code will be something like this:

```
const queryResult = did => query.getCachedData(did).then(tfnData => tfnData);

// Without async/await    
queryResult(did)
  .then(data => {
    const { name, country } = data;
    const result = { name, country };
    console.log(`${result.name}, ${result.country}`); // Jon, US
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(`Error produced: ${error}`));

// With async/await
(async () => {
  try {
    // ... Some other code ....
    // ... Some other code ....
    // ... Some other code ....

    const data = await queryResult(did);
    const { name, country } = data;
    const result = { name, country };
    console.log(`${result.name}, ${result.country}`); // Jon, US
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Error inside try-catch: ${error}`);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that `await` waits for an `async` function to return a promise. For your code example, I would suggest the following:

```
let result={
    name:'',
    country:''
};

async function getData() {
    const data = await query.getCachedData(did);
    result.name = data.name; // 'Jon'
    result.country = data.country; // 'US'
    console.log(result);
}
```

`await` can only be used inside an `async` function. It will pause the function until a promise is received from `query.getCachedData()`, save that response into `const data` which can then be used to set the name and country of the `result` object. You can also look at the MDN docs for both [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Answer (score 0):

`await` does not make your asynchronous code synchronous - and there should not be any reasonable reason to do so ... behind the scenes it returns a promise and chain it with then instead of you having to chain it with then yourself.

What you did with the then keyword, is what the `await` did for you.

You can use whatever suits you, but `async/await` makes your code easier to read.

if this works

```
result.name = await data.name;
```

this means that the **name** is an async getter function that you have to *await* for it to get the result. You can do it also like this
`data.name.then(name => doWhateverYouWantWithName(name))` or using the `await` keyword like you already did - and that should be better even.